Newbie needs help: How to combine two linux partitions
I have run out of space on a partition, and I would like to combine it with
an adjacent partition.  Here is the order of the partitions on disk.
sda7    ext4    mate 16.04 (old smaller partition)
sda5    ext4    mate 20.04 (larger partition out of space)

I would like to end up with one partition containing everything in the sda5
partition.  It is okay if the contents of the sda7 partition are lost.
I have used gparted and fdisk minimally, but never done anything like moving
partitions or combining them, so I would appreciate very detailed
instructions.
I am running Ubuntu MATE:
Release 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 4.4.0-210-generic x86_64
MATE 1.12.1

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

Does this answer your question? How to resize partitions?

Your question (as delivered) is off-topic as it concentrates on the EOL/EOSS release of Ubuntu (off-topic)...  If you'd worded your question about the 20.04 system, whilst Ubuntu-MATE 20.04 LTS is EOL, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS isn't thus your question would have been on-topic here..  Boot a live system & just delete the unwanted partition (if you don't want anything on it; otherwise save/move what you want to keep elsewhere first) & expand the other to use that space (and move/restore back whatever you wanted to keep from other partition)  If encryption is involved its more complex
